# Instantiate object that takes a Resolve<Interface>

Tags: c#, botframework, autofac

I am getting error that scope does not exist in current context when I call `await SendAsync(activity, scope => new TransferToAgentDialog(scope.Resolve<IUserToAgent>()))` . The scope needs to pass in `scope.Resolve<IUserToAgent>` when it It initializes new `TransferToAgentDialog` class.

I have tried initializing scope:

```
public TransferToAgent scope = new TransferToAgent(scope.Reslove<IUserToAgent>);
```

This however presents the problem that you cannot pass the `scope.Resolve<IUserToAgent>` when inintializing `scope`.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await SendAsync(activity, scope => new TransferToAgentDialog(scope.Resolve<IUserToAgent>()));
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

***SendAsync Class***

```
private async Task SendAsync(IMessageActivity toBot, Func<ILifetimeScope, IDialog<object>> MakeRoot, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, toBot))
    {
        DialogModule_MakeRoot.Register(scope, () => MakeRoot(scope));
        var task = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
        await task.PostAsync(toBot, token);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am getting error that scope does not exist in current context" -> where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate scope like this:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
    {
        await SendAsync(activity, () => new TransferToAgentDialog(scope.Resolve<IUserToAgent>()));                       
    }
```